# How to get the Maven project window in Intellij 14 | Update: cannot see the right side "tab bar" with Maven project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a very simple question, but I Googled and somehow I couldn't find it. I was wondering how can I get the

[image: Maven Project Pane]

in Intellij 14 or something similar?

I saw it in a tutorial, but couldn't find the panel. In my case when I followed this [video](https://youtu.be/Sc2atFv_h_I?list=PL4gCdGOq-cxJrbRMWjrIvGhYqQO1tvYyX) exactly, I couldn't see the panel and I couldn't find it anywhere. I have IntelliJ 14.

**UPDATE**
I just experimented a bit with the Intellij interface but I can't seem to see the right hand side bar. See

[image]

Comment: I believe it is a default window. For me the Maven Projects button is on the far right hand side of IntelliJ just like your picture. Have you tried resetting the IDE windows? Go to Window->Restore Default Layout.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. It would be better if someone has a better option than using my "last resort" option.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

First, make sure you have enabled maven plugin in

`File` → `Settings` → `Plugins` → `Maven Integration`

If so and still the tool window is hidden then

go to `View` → `Tool Windows` → `Maven Projects` to open it.

Comment: I tried that, but does not seem to work, I got a project with POM imported and can see the POM, the Plugin for Maven Integration installed and enabled, but don't have the option to choose Maven Toolwindow..

Answer (score 316):

I had similar problem until I right-clicked the option in POM "Add as Maven Project".

[image]

Notice: *IDEA 2019.2* and I couldn't even find Maven in "Tool Windows" of the (existing) project before it.

Comment: Same for version 2019.2. This is the only way.

Comment: Thanks.  I imported several maven projects from eclipse and the "Add as Maven Project" option on the pom was the only way to enable the Maven view.

Comment: This is the fix for 2020.2 as well.

Comment: really interesting, couldn't activate it on any other way, this fixed it also for me at the end ... thanks (got latest version but i updated it from an older one)

Comment: You're a life saviour. I had to twice reclone my repo and add configs and still couldn't figure out the issue.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. I installed the latest version of intellij and didn't notice that it had removed all of my projects from maven. I had to add them all back manually.

Comment: Cheers to you! Solved this for me!!

Answer (score 38):

For those stuck with this issue, enable View -> Tool Buttons.

Answer (score 27):

Finally found the solution, right-click on the pom.xml file (parent pom.xml if it is a multi-module project) and hit "add as a maven project".

Comment: I never rmbr this, but the right solution is always down below for more recent versions of software which keeps getting changed a lot in prefs.

Answer (score 20):

You can find the Maven Projects pane by going to Help > Find Action or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and type in "Maven Projects". However I can't see it anywhere in the elaborate menu's.

Comment: ^ The actual answer.

Answer (score 14):

Simple solution to see maven on intelliJ is go to your right click on your pom.xml and then click on Add as Maven project.

Comment: This helped a lot in my project, maven wasn't updating in build and this solved it!

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with a maven project, the tab wasn't showing up and even in the View->Tool windows menu, there was no maven item.
After searching the internet i could not find a solution but then i looked in Intellij idea
 and noticed a Even Log showing a number in a red circle, i clicked it and then read an error message:

```
Non-managed pom.xml file found:   
Add as Maven Project
```

check out solution proposed by invzbl3, It might help.

Answer (score 5):

The question asked is how to show the sidebar, not show the Maven Plugin. On my version of Intellij this is enabled with the following:

View -> Appearance -> Tool Window Bars

Comment: This one should be the correct solution, as original author had problem with missing toolbar, not a plugins disabled\not installed.
And it worked for me! Thanks a lot, Scott!

Comment: Much helpful amongst all. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

Very simple. NO PLUGINS.

Maven comes by default so you should press two times the shift key and write "maven".

Then import the maven project ".pom" and the bar cames automatically after selecting the pom.

Answer (score 4):

if you have a pom file in your project, right click the file, click "add as maven project"

This got it back for me. None of the other solutions worked. I had no warnings for unmanged poms, toggling toolbars did not help and the maven option just where it should be anywhere!

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on your project > Add Framework Support > Maven

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit late, but I had the same problem with missing sidebars. At least in IDEA 2017.3 there is an icon on the bottom left of the screen that toggles the sidebars. That's how I got it back.

Answer (score 1):

Weird but this works at times:

Disable File → Settings → Plugins → Maven Integration first and restart Intellij. Then re-enable it back and restart - this might fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If View → Tool Windows → Maven Projects doesnt work that means tools button is deselected

go to View -> Tool Buttons and select it . You should be able to Maven window now

Comment: Not able to see this option in the view, can you please help

Answer (score 1):

Try with File-->Project structure --> Modules-> Remove Parent/existing modules and add parent/all modules again

Answer (score 1):

None above helped.
In my case I had to ad Java SDK. It keeps disappearing for some reason.
Right click on project folder `-> Open Module settings -> Project` in this window define SDK under `SDK:`

Maven toolbar appeared after doing that.

Answer (score 1):

No Need to do any settings i have attached the image of intelij in that marked area click on that multi window suport then you will be able to access the panels for all

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enable maven plugin first in

> `File → Settings → Plugins → Maven`

Also, make sure you enable Tool Buttons in

> `View → Tool Buttons`

Answer (score 0):

Check if at the bottom line of Intellij, it says "non-managed pom files found."

You can then "Add as a Maven Project"

Comment: this is just another repost

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Maven plugin is enabled as well. In my case, it was disabled for an unknown reason. To enable it: Settings → Plugins → Installed (Scroll down to Bundled section)

Answer (score 0):

If you not use Maven, can delete it.

open `ProjectName.iml` file in root of project of module.

then remove "`org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule="true"`" from file.

save and reBuild project.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my maven integration plugin got disabled.

Go to IntelliJ Idea --> Preferences
and enable Maven integration plugin.

Looks like Intellij Idea disables dependent plugin also, when one of the plugins are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the home directory of the project is correct. I was creating Intellij project one level above the actual maven project folder and that's why the maven tool window wasn't showing.

Answer (score 0):

1. `View -> Appearance -> Tool Windows Bar`
2. `View -> Tool Window -> Maven`

This will add maven window

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-232.9921.47, built on September 12, 2023

My solution was to delete the `.idea` directory in project

1. close IntelliJ.
2. `rm -Rf .idea`
3. start intelliJ again