# org.json Class Not Found With Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, org.json

I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException when trying to work with JSONObjects in my Minecraft plugin. I have it added to my build path (I'm using IntelliJ) and I have it added as a Maven dependency. I've tried to google a solution, but I was unsuccessful hence I decided to make a post.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I've tried to remove the scope but it doesn't work without it, either.
Here is my stacktrace (formatting messed up as code so I have to pastebin): http://pastebin.com/Q5QVd2S8

StatsCommand 48:

```
UUID uuid = UUIDFetcher.fetchUUID("arraying");
```

My UUIDFetcher fetchUUID method:

```
    public static UUID fetchUUID(String playerName) {
    UUID uuid = null;
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(new URL("https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/" + playerName), Charsets.UTF_8));
        uuid = UUID.fromString(jsonObject.getString("id"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (!(e instanceof JSONException))
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return uuid;
}
```

I've tried this exact same code with the exact same dependencies on another project, and it worked there. I don't know why this isn't working here.

Comment: Sounds like you've not ran your code using Maven

Comment: @cricket_007 What do you mean?

Comment: Like you've clicked Run in Intellij, which isn't running the Maven tasks, it's just executing your code, regardless of the dependencies you've set. You can try to open the Maven window view (on the right side) to do clean and package.

Comment: @cricket_007 I can't run the program (because this is Minecraft :l), I export it and put it in a folder where it gets accessed. I don't see a button for cleaning and packaging in my Maven window, what does it look like?

Comment: The toolbar along the right side of Intellij should have a Maven panel. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126432/how-to-get-the-maven-project-window-in-intellij-14-update-cannot-see-the-righ

Comment: How do you export the code?? You need to package it with Maven into a jar file, not just export using Intellij options

Comment: @cricket_007 I make an artifact and add all the Maven dependencies to it.