# Why "Add as Maven Project:" option is missing in POM - IntelliJ 2019

Tags: intellij-idea, pom.xml

I had issues downloading dependencies in my Java project. I used [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126432/how-to-get-the-maven-project-window-in-intellij-14-update-cannot-see-the-righ) solution which worked for me.

But some of my projects POM files doesn't have that option in the `POM.xml` instead of `Add as Maven Project`, I can see `Add as Ant build File`

Is there any settings to change this?

intelliJ-Ultimate - `2019.13`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like initially you can see that option (i.e. `Add as Maven Project`) and once you run that option the other menu which specified in the question shows up.

There you get `Reimport` option to re fetch if needed.